# Problems with splitt out SIP-Address from AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to split out the sip_address in folder `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync` Since I have more than one active SIP-addresses I have some problems getting the one I need in this example it would be `example2@example2.com`

There might also be more SIP-addresses in this folder, but I would only like to have the one example2.

I started with sorting out all subfolder in directory giving me a result:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync\sip_example1@example1.com
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync\sip_example2@example2.com
C:\Users\c%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync\Tracing
```

And here is where face issues with splitting as my code are not good at all and the result would be:

> example2@example2.comC:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync\Tracing

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim SIPAccount As String
    Private Sub GETSipAccount()

        ' Path and SIP-Addresses has been anonymous due to personal addresses.

        For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync")

            ' List out directory
            SIPAccount = SIPAccount & Dir & vbNewLine

            On Error Resume Next ' I do not want to include this in my application at all

            ' Splits out text
            SIPAccount = ((Split(Split(SIPAccount, "sip_")(1), "@example2.com")(0))) & "@example2.com"
            MsgBox(SIPAccount)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        GETSipAccount()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending if the "example2" string part is unique to the directory address you could use something like

```
Dim lst As List(Of String) = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:...").ToList
MessageBox.Show(lst.FindAll(Function(x) x.Contains("example2"))(0))
```

if you want to compare just the last part of the string you could use something like

```
Dim lst As List(Of String) = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:...").ToList

For Each item As String In lst

    Dim lastindexofbackslash As Integer = item.LastIndexOf("\")

    Dim _item As String = item.Substring(lastindexofbackslash + 1)

    If _item.Contains("example2") Then

        MsgBox(_item.Substring(4))

    End If

Next
```

Comment: Hello, Markus. I appreciate your reply to my post. This helped me a lot. Both of them works for my application.